# Visualforce - Checkboxes not getting rendered on Public Site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

This is my public site displaying list of records from a custom object.

As you can see the delete input checkboxes are not getting rendered but they are rendered as expected within Salesforce.

Can someone explain this odd behavior ?

Screenshot within Salesforce

[image]

This is my VF Page.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Expense__c" extensions="ExpenseController"  sidebar="false" showHeader="true" showChat="false" recordSetVar="exp" >
<script src="../../soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<apex:form >
<!--<apex:panelGrid columns="20">-->
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!isTwenty}">Previous</apex:commandLink>
<tab/><tab/>
<apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!isTwenty}">Next</apex:commandLink>

<!--</apex:panelGrid>-->

<apex:inlineEditSupport />

<apex:pageBlock title="List of Expenses">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!exp}" var="item" >
<apex:column headerValue="Delete" width="20px">
<apex:inputCheckbox onchange="alert('Are you sure ?');" value="{!item.IsDeletedFromUI__c}" rendered="true"  />
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Date" >
<apex:outputField value="{!item.Date__c}" />
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Type">
<apex:outputField value="{!item.Type__c}"/>
</apex:column>

<apex:column headerValue="Amount">
<apex:outputField value="{!item.Amount__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Comments">
<apex:outputField value="{!item.Comments__c}"/>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<p>Sum of All Expenses : Rs {!SumOfAllExpenses}</p>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" id="theButton1" />
<!--<apex:commandButton action="{!custom_delete}" value="Delete" id="theButton2" />-->
<!--<apex:commandButton value="Total" id="theButton2" onclick="alert('Deleting the expense...')"/>-->
<apex:pageBlock title="Enter Password for Deletion: " >
<apex:inputSecret value="{!pwd}" />
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Check the Field level security of that field for guest user and make sure its not read only.It should be visible.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the pointer. That was the issue. Can you post this as answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Field level security of that field for guest user and make sure its not read only.It should be visible